Was the Prophet (SWL) Really Served a Severed Head?

“After ‘Amr ibn Hisham was mortally wounded by a new convert to Islam during the Battle of Badr, Abdullah ibn Mas’ud saw ‘Amr collapsed on the ground. So he went to him and started abusing him. Among other things, Abdullah grabbed and pulled ‘Amr’s beard and stood in triumph on the dying man’s chest.”
— Unknown Source


“After that, Abdullah slit ‘Amr’s head off and bore it till he placed it between the hands of the Prophet. Thus did Allah heal the hearts of the believers with it.”
— Al-Bidaya wa Nihaya, by Ibn Kathir


“When the apostle had finished with the enemy, he ordered that Abū Jahl should be looked for amongst the slain. Abdullah ibn Mas’ud said, 'You have climbed high, you little shepherd.' Then I cut off his head and brought it to the apostle saying, "This is the head of the enemy of God, Abū Jahl.' He said, 'By God than Whom there is no other, is it?' 'Yes,' I said, and I threw his head before the apostle and he gave thanks to God.”
— Al-Sirah al-Nabawiyyah, by Ibn Ishaq, (1/ 304)


“Abdullah ibn Mas’ud placed his foot on the dying foe of Islam, ‘Amr opened his eyes and recognized him. The once proud chieftain lamented that he was being killed by a common “goat herder,” to which Abdullah replied, “Islam elevates and nothing is elevated above it.” He then sheared his head off. “But he could not carry it, so he made holes in the ears and put thread through them and dragged the head to the prophet. Then Gabriel, peace be upon him, came laughing and saying, “O prophet, you got an ear and an ear—and the head between for a bonus!”
— Tafsir Al-Alusi, Q96:15


“Mu‘awwidh ibn ‘Afrā’ passed Hishām as he lay there "helpless and smote" him until he left him at his last gasp. He himself went on fighting until he was killed. Then 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ūd passed by Hishām when the Apostle had ordered that he was to be searched for among the slain. 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ūd said that he found him at his last gasp and put his foot on his neck and said to him: "Has God put you to shame?" He replied, "How has He shamed me? Am I anything more remarkable than a man you have killed? Tell me how the battle went." He told him that it went in favor of Allah and His apostle. Hishām said, "You have climbed high, you little shepherd." Then ['Abdullah ibn Mas'ūd] struck off his head and showed his head to Muhammad. When Muhammad saw his lifeless body on the battlefield he said, "This is the Pharaoh of this Ummah. Upon his death, the people of Quraysh mourned for him and composed elegies and requiems depicting him as a "noble, generous and glorified man."”
— The Pharaoh of the Community

The focus of this ticket is as follows:

What is the authenticity of these narrations?
Is the overall story of Ibn Mas'ud beheading Abu Jahl and showing
the prophet (swl) his head even authentic?
Why did the prophet (swl) order his companions to search for Abu Jahl?

